# Make Travis-CI run *both* Python 2 and 3

Tags: python, shell, travis-ci

Should hopefully be a pretty basic question, but here is my `.travis.yml` file below:

```
language: python

python:
    - "2.6"
    - "2.7"
    - "3.2"
    - "3.3"
    - "3.4"
    - "3.5"
    - "nightly"

matrix:
  allow_failures:
    - python: "2.6"
    - python: "3.2"
    - python: "3.3"
    - python: "3.4"
    - python: "nightly"

install:
    - pip install -r requirements.pip
    - pip install -r test/requirements.pip

script: python -B test/test.py
```

If you look at the script at the bottom, it's the Python 2 command, whereas `python3` is for Python 3. As you can see up top, I choose to use versions from both Python 2 *and* 3.

I want to ask, **will that bottom script argument suffice? I want Travis to run my script on every single version that I chose above.**

I also chose to ask before just uploading it and trying, because I just want to upload the `.yml` and have it work on the spot. Without making several commits trying to cleanup small errors and putting build-fails everywhere.

Comment: I realize that this might not be the actual code, but I hope you're not supporting 2.6 and 3.2 any longer :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Take a look [**here**](https://travis-ci.org/finnrayment/dash-h), its beautiful! As for 2.6. Looks like I won't be with this error... Why shouldn't I support 3.2?

Comment: 3.2 was EOLed a long time ago, and it doesn't support the portability features that exist in 3.3 - doesn't for example support the `u''` strings.

Comment: BTW travis already supports [Python 3.6 as it should](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/python/)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Oh. Well I actually need `u''` strings! :O Thankyou for the information, I don't use Python enough to know version issues. Also good to know 3.6 is ready! Will add that in now. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. `python` can be pointing to any version of Python, and in fact it defaults to 3 in some distros like Arch. virtualenv which Travis uses links python to the specified version.

Debugging tips: if you want to avoid polluting commit history, create a branch to work on it and squash/rebase merge later.

Answer (score 1):

The command `python` will always mean one of the Python versions from the matrix; i.e. your build will be executed 5 times, each time `python` pointing a different version from that list.

The version number for the current sub-build available in the `TRAVIS_PYTHON_VERSION` environment variable.